# Calling base class template constructor in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor

I have a template base class which has a constructor for conversion from any other template instantiation of that class, like this:

```
template <class T>
class FooBase
{
public:

    FooBase()
    {
    }

    template <class U>
    FooBase(const FooBase<U>& other)
    {
        std::cout << "FooBase<U>" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Notice how there is no copy constructor defined.

I then have a derived template class which does have a copy constructor, as well as the constructor used for conversion:

```
template <class T>
class Foo : public FooBase<T>
{
public:

    Foo()
    {
    }

    Foo(const Foo& other) :
        FooBase<T>(other)
    {
    }

    template <class U>
    Foo(const Foo<U>& other) :
        FooBase<T>(other)
    {
    }
};
```

Because `FooBase` doesn't have a copy constructor, this results in `FooBase<T>(other)` making a call to the compiler-generated copy constructor. Which means if I run this:

```
int main()
{
    Foo<int> a;
    Foo<int> b(a);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is **nothing**, when it should be `FooBase<U>`.

Of course, I could try to solve the issue by creating a copy constructor in `FooBase` and using [delegating constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor):

```
    FooBase(const FooBase& other)
        : FooBase<T>(other)
    {
    }
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work, and it would result in a recursive call as the compiler helpfully points out:

```
warning C4717: 'FooBase<int>::FooBase<int>': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
```

So the only solution would be to duplicate the logic into both constructors.

Is there any way around this that doesn't involve code duplication or a separate initialization function?

Comment: That's because `FooBase<T>` actually names the current class, and thus the delegation goes back to the copy constructor, not to the constructor template.

Comment: You could use directly a template typename instead of FooBase<U>, however you would incur in [this problem](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/a-conditional-copy-constructor/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a third, private constructor that both the copy constructor and the constructor template delegate to and which contains the actual work:

```
template <typename T> class FooBase
{
    struct Tag{};

    template <typename U>  // May have U = T
    FooBase(Tag, const FooBase<U> & rhs)
    {
        // actual implementation
    }

public:
    FooBase(const FooBase & rhs) : FooBase(Tag(), rhs) {}

    template <typename U>  // Never selects U = T
    FooBase(const FooBase<U> & rhs) : FooBase(Tag(), rhs) {}
};
```